# Expression Blend The Prereleased version of this product has expired

Tags: expression-blend

I have one problem.it's regarding error of Expression blend before 1 week my expression blend preview for silverlight 5 was working fine but today when I start it it will give me error like "**The Prereleased version of this product has expired you must update a new version**"

I have tried a lot to find update of Microsoft Expression blend preview for Silverlight 5 didn't find it.

Anyone please help me ....

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Visual Studio 2012 installed, please install at least the Update 2 which restores WPF and Silverlight functionality in Blend for Visual Studio 2012.

[Link to Update 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600) (includes updates 1 & 2)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I haven't installed VS2012 I am using VS2010